# Connection refused : Nginx HTTPS reverse proxy in docker container

Tags: nginx, https, docker, proxy, reverse-proxy

I wanted to setup `https` reverse proxy with nginx on docker container either ubuntu/centos. On Browser side, I am getting `connection refused` error. And also, I cannot see anything under `/var/log/nginx/access.log` or `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

I am able to setup `http` reverse proxy with nginx on docker container again. And, also `https` reverse proxy with nginx on normal ubuntu and centos virtual machines.

Can understand the reason why `https` reverse proxy with nginx on docker containers is failing to connect from browser.?

If any additional information needed, I can provide you. Thanks in advance.

For reference, Please check this `sites-available/default` file.

```
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name localhost;

      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;

      ssl on;
      ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
      ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

      location ~* /rabbitmq/(.*) {
        rewrite ^\/rabbitmq\/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15672;
        proxy_set_header Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
      }

      location ~* /api/(.*) {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
      }
    }
```

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the command which you are using to initiate it

Comment: @manojprashantk `# docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx-container`

Comment: have you tried the suggested answer? by @Andrey Chausenko .
I believe there is something wrong with the ports. In your nginx-container is the 3000 port open? like we give `EXPOSE 3000` while creating the docker image. have you given that?

Comment: The nginx server running on ports 80, 443 and the above configuration is meant to be **passing requests to proxied server on ports 3000 and 15672** in my case. So, I have exposed 80 in the Dockerfile. Looks, I have to expose 443 as well to allow https. That is missing in my `docker run`command. Now, the command should be `#docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 nginx-container`. Thanks @manojprashantk for your help.

Comment: oopsie i didnt notice `port 443` . Yes that should fix your issue

Comment: Thanks @manojprashantk for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks, I need to expose both HTTP and HTTPS ports, since nginx reverse proxy configured to server only HTTPS traffic.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 nginx-container
```

When I started exposing HTTPS port, then it worked.

Comment: Not exactly the same case, but understanding that the certbot communication works over HTTP, rather than HTTPS, helped me get to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running your container in "bridge" network mode (it's default), which means that your *127.0.0.1* is not what you think it is. It would use virtualised network adapter for your container running **nginx**. To quickly fix it you can add

```
--net=host
```

parameter to your **docker run** command. There are other options, but I need to know more about your setup and requirements to suggest them.

Comment: It seems, I was mistaken,  **need to expose https port 443 along with http port 80 when doing https reverse proxy** as mentioned the configuration given above. Now, it works for the command `# docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 nginx-container`. Thanks for the inputs.